# Can any one help me how to design this screen below

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrt6y.jpg)I want to design this screen using android widgets can anyone help me how i design this using right widgets.
I might thing that expandable list view will b good for this but how i create dynamic tabs in its child view?
Parent
Child(Dynamic tabs)
or any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest

> CoordinateLayout
>
> TabLayout(Scrolling)
>
> inside every tab use LinearLayout with  height for 100dp (HOrizental)
>   put your items in linear layout
>
> then in every fragment of Tab use recylerview for best performance
>
> then in every fragment also use another tab layout for years
>
> and then for every year also  inside every tab use LinearLayout with 
>   height for 100dp (HOrizental)
>
> put your items in linear layout
>
> and then every year Tab ,use recylerView